# Get second highest salary from each deptno

Tags: sql

How do I get second highest salary from each `deptno` from the following table?

```
ID NAME                        AGE     DEPTNO     SALARY
-- -------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
 1 shasank                      25         11       2025
 2 raju                         27         12       2027
 3 son                          33         12       2131
 6 bali                         31         10       2031
 4 rambo                        34         11       2345
 5 don                          32         11       2132
 7 dimpu                        31         12       2121
 8 rahul                        28         10       2341
 9 janny                        28         10       2123
```

Comment: HE has marked sql in tag. So its clear

Comment: @Jatin Dhoot: Solutions for SQL Server 2005 will be different to MySQL...

Comment: Do you need the answer via one query, or can you have multiple queries?

Comment: Hey gbn, I meant to say that if it would have been mysql ----- user would have included mysql in tag.

Comment: @Jatin - SQL is a language implemented by multiple RDBMS products - SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL... There are specific tags for sql-server, so gbn's question is reasonable.

Comment: When you can tell us what SQL server product you're using then flag to re-open.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a system that supports the SQL ranking functions, then DENSE_RANK is probably what you're seeking. Below is for SQL Server 2005 or later:

```
SELECT
    * --TODO - pick columns
FROM
    (
        SELECT *,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DeptNo ORDER BY Salary DESC) as Rnk
        FROM Table
    )
WHERE
    Rnk = 2
```

([SQL Server documentation on DENSE_RANK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx))

Comment: Will this not fail if there is only one deptno? Say, in the above example, there is a deptno 9 which has only one row. Your query will skip it as "rnk=2".

Comment: @6055 - **if** your data contains such possibilities, then you need to define what "2nd highest salary" would *mean* in that situation. The solution doesn't *fail*. Your comment seems to assume that a row should still exist (but doesn't imply what the result should be), but that was not a requirement that was specified in the question.

Answer (score 0):

First retrieve top 2 records then create alias of that table, then retrieve record order by desc

Answer (score 0):

Try This
    SELECT TOP 2 FROM 'TableName' Limit 1,1 Order By DESC

Comment: What engine is this for?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

SELECT * FROM ( 
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Salary DESC) as row FROM 
 ) a WHERE row > 1 and row <= 2

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but that `WHERE` clause has to be one of the worst ways of expressing `row=2` I've ever encountered. (I was woken by a comment on my answer)